# Lasagne LSTM regression produces zerros as output

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, lstm, lasagne

Inspired by Andrej Karpathy's [blog](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/) i wanted to make my own version of a recurrent neural network that selects the next word instead of character.
Because of the number of different words in a text is so many, i used [word2vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) to represent the words as vectors (where similar words are closer in the vector-space). The NN should now train to learn the new vector from the pattern of old ones.

-one important note is that where Karpathy used a classifier, i am trying a regression method (squared loss cost).

**My problem is that my neural network predicts the output [0,0,0....,0] no matter how much training. so my guess is that there is a problem in my method of training or prediction (the average error drops a little during training, so some training must be done)**

below is my entire code if anyone wants to run it (it uses the brown corpus so requires installation of nltk to work as is).

This is my "Hello World" project in Lasagne, so any pointers if i do something stupid is appreciated.
Thanks in advance :)

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
import gensim
import sys
from datetime import timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from nltk.corpus import brown
import theano.tensor as T
import theano
import time
import numpy as np
from lasagne import layers
import lasagne
from lasagne.updates import nesterov_momentum
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE


def modelExcept(input, model, size):
    try:
        out = model[input]
        return out
    except Exception:
        out = np.zeros((size))
        print 'exception ' + str(input)
        return out

def plot_TSNE(model,nr_words=None):
    tsne = TSNE(n_components=2)
    if nr_words == None:
        X_tsne = tsne.fit_transform(model[model.wv.vocab][:])
    else:  
        X_tsne = tsne.fit_transform(model[model.wv.vocab][0:nr_words])

    X_names =  [key for key in model.wv.vocab]
    plt.figure()
    ax = plt.subplot(111)
    for i in range(X_tsne.shape[0]):
        plt.text(X_tsne[i, 0], X_tsne[i, 1], str(X_names[i]),
                    #color=plt.cm.Set1(y[i] / 10.),
                    fontdict={'weight': 'bold', 'size': 9})

    plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.draw()
    #plt.scatter(X_tsne[:, 0], X_tsne[:, 1])
    #plt.show()

def getBatch(words_as_vecs , wordSize,totalwords, windowSize, BATCHSIZE):

    BatchIndexes = np.random.randint(0,totalwords-windowSize, size=BATCHSIZE)
    input = np.empty((BATCHSIZE,windowSize,wordSize),dtype=np.float32)
    target = np.empty((BATCHSIZE,wordSize),dtype=np.float32)
    for i in range(BATCHSIZE):
        k = BatchIndexes[i]
        input[i,:,:] = words_as_vecs[k:k+windowSize,:]
        target[i,:] = words_as_vecs[k+windowSize,:]

    return input, target


wordSize = 30
windowSize = 5
BATCHSIZE = 128
LEARNING_RATE = .1
Nr_EPOCHS = 100
NR_Predictions = 15


model_raw = Word2Vec(brown.sents(),workers=4,window=10,iter=15,size=wordSize, min_count=10)
#plot_TSNE(model_raw,None)
model = model_raw.wv #trim model after training to save RAM
del model_raw

words_filtered = filter(lambda x: x in model.vocab, brown.words())#filter away words that are not in vocabulary
words_as_vecs = np.asarray([modelExcept(word, model,wordSize) for word in words_filtered],dtype = np.float32) #create all vector representations beforehand to save time!!
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
words_as_vecs = scaler.fit_transform(words_as_vecs)

print 'creating neural net...'

Num_units_per_layer = 512
GRAD_CLIP = 100
l_in = lasagne.layers.InputLayer(shape=(None,None,wordSize))
l_LSTM1 = lasagne.layers.LSTMLayer(l_in,Num_units_per_layer,grad_clipping=GRAD_CLIP,nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.rectify)
l_drop1 = lasagne.layers.DropoutLayer(l_LSTM1,p=0.5)
l_LSTM2 = lasagne.layers.LSTMLayer(l_drop1,Num_units_per_layer,grad_clipping=GRAD_CLIP,nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.rectify, only_return_final=True)
l_drop2 = lasagne.layers.DropoutLayer(l_LSTM2,p=0.5)
l_shp = lasagne.layers.ReshapeLayer(l_drop2,(-1,Num_units_per_layer))
l_out = lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(l_shp,num_units=wordSize,W=lasagne.init.Normal(), nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.rectify)

target_vals = T.imatrix('target values')
net_out = lasagne.layers.get_output(l_out)
net_out_predict = lasagne.layers.get_output(l_out,deterministic = True)

#use squared error because the problem is now a regession problem
cost = T.sum(lasagne.objectives.squared_error(net_out,target_vals))

all_params = lasagne.layers.get_all_params(l_out, trainable = True)
updates = lasagne.updates.adagrad(cost, all_params, LEARNING_RATE)

net_train = theano.function([l_in.input_var, target_vals], cost, updates=updates, allow_input_downcast=True)
compute_cost = theano.function([l_in.input_var, target_vals], cost, allow_input_downcast=True)
net_predict = theano.function([l_in.input_var],net_out_predict,allow_input_downcast=True)

print 'creating testphrase...'
testphrase_vectors = np.empty((1,5,wordSize),dtype=np.float32)
testphrase_vectors[0,:,:] = words_as_vecs[1:6,:]
testphrase_words = words_filtered[0:6]
#testphrase_words = brown.words()[0:6]

print 'training...'
avg_cost = 0
totalwords = len(words_filtered)
#totalwords = len(brown.words())
print_freq = totalwords/BATCHSIZE #print example every epoch

nrItterations = Nr_EPOCHS*totalwords/BATCHSIZE

for i in range(nrItterations):
    inTrain, target = getBatch(words_as_vecs, wordSize, totalwords, windowSize, BATCHSIZE)
    avg_cost += net_train(inTrain,target)

    #generate text sample
    if (i%print_freq == 0) and (i != 0):
        print 'prediction of train'

        print 'average cost is {0}' .format(avg_cost/(BATCHSIZE*print_freq))
        avg_cost = 0
        generated_example = ' '.join(testphrase_words)
        testphrase_vectors_copy = testphrase_vectors
        for k in range(NR_Predictions):
            prediction = np.asarray(net_predict(testphrase_vectors_copy))
            prediction_unscaled = scaler.inverse_transform(prediction.reshape(1,-1)).reshape(-1)
            current_word = model.most_similar(positive=[prediction_unscaled], topn=1)

            generated_example = ' '.join((generated_example, current_word[0][0]))

            #insert new word in testphrase (and delete first)
            testphrase_vectors_copy[0,0:-1,:] = testphrase_vectors_copy[0,1:,:]
            testphrase_vectors_copy[0,-1,:] = model[current_word[0][0]]
            #print testphrase_vectors_copy
        print 'example nr. {}' .format(i/print_freq + 1)
        print generated_example
        print '\n \n'
```

Comment: I haven't looked at this in detail as I don't work in Lasagne, but I would question whether you have formed your model correctly for regression in that you are using a squared error loss function, but the output of your model runs through a relu activation function which seems an odd approach. I may just not have come across this approach before.

Comment: thanks for the response. I previously tried scaling the word vectors in the range [-1,1] and using a tanh activation function, but the result there was the same. The reason i have relu now is just to encourage sparce activity.

Comment: How are your labels (ground truth data) structured and what do you mean by a regression approach? I initially assumed you meant a linear regression approach (which would align with using squared error), in which case I would use no activation after the final dense layer. If you meant logistic regression  (which seems a bit of a wrong categorisation ) and your labels are one hot encoded, then I would have thought you need to softmax the result after the relu activation before using the loss function to compare the output to the label.

Comment: Ahh, i see what you are saying. No activation function is interesting and i will indeed try it out (and remove the MinMaxScaler). 
I think i will end up scaling the target vectors to the interval [-1,1]  and use a tanh activation.
I also found the error in my code, so everything works now :)
- thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the error.

The problem was this line:

target_vals = T.imatrix('target values')

which should be:

target_vals = T.fmatrix('target values')

since i'm aiming after floats and not integers.